# MongoDB - How to atomically increase a number and get the new value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency, atomic

Basically I need to increase an counter in an document and get the new value, but this has to work atomically.

Current I'm using the command:

```
.updateOne({_id: ObjectId('5ed7f23789bcd51e9c6a82e0')}, {$inc: {nextTicket: 1}})
```

But I can't find how to immediately get the new incremented value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`updateOne` does not return the document / the documents fields.

What you want to do is use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). now this still returns the "old" document so you want to specify `returnOriginal: false`

```
.findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId('5ed7f23789bcd51e9c6a82e0')}, {$inc: {nextTicket: 1}}, {returnOriginal: false})
```

Comment: I just saw that stack overflow auto-corrected "atomically" to "automatically", post edited.

Is `findOneAndUpdate` atomic?

Comment: Yes, all of Mongo's single write operators are atomic.

Comment: I didn't realize this function existed so all my updates do `UpdateOne()` and then `return FindOne()`. I might have to refactor my code as I'm assuming to distinct operations, update then find, would be slower than one operation, findAndUpdate.

Comment: You should do this as otherwise you will lose atomicity.